# Thread-safety idiom for getters in a Java class other than "synchronized"

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class ThreadSafe {

    private int aField;

    public synchronized void setAField(int value) {
        aField = value;
    }

    public synchronized int getAField() {
        return aField;
    }

}

public class ThreadSafeToo {

    private volatile int aField;

    public synchronized void setAField(int value) {
        aField = value;
    }

    public int getAField() {
        return aField;
    }

}

public class DontKnowIfThreadSafeButMostLikelyYes {

    private static int aField;

    public synchronized void setAField(int value) {
        aField = value;
    }

    public int getAField() {
        return aField;
    }

}
```

Questions:

- Is DontKnowIfThreadSafeButMostLikelyYes thread-safe?
- What would be the preferred idiom and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ThreadSafeToo` does not need a synchronized method: volatile assignment is atomic and provides visibility guarantees.

`DontKnowIfThreadSafeButMostLikelyYes` is not thread safe: you need to synchronize reads AND writes to shared variables.

Preferred idiom is subjective, but in your case, the efficient approach is:

```
public class ThreadSafeToo {
    private volatile int aField;
    public void setAField(int value) { aField = value; }
    public int getAField() { return aField; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't a write to an `int` atomic as well?

Comment: @archer cHao is probably referring to a 32-bit atomic write, where as you don't have two separate writes having a jumbled output.  You will see either one write or another so in that case a write to a 32-bit in *is* atomic.  The atomicity mentioned by assylias has to do with memory visibility.

Comment: @JohnVint: That's what i was referring to.  I hadn't seen the word "atomic" used in the context of visibility before.

Comment: @cHao Atomic in this case is important because you cannot do compound operations with volatile, such as `volatile int a = 0; a++;` is neither atomic nor thread-safe

Comment: @archer Agreed, but that isn't what cHao was asking.

Comment: @JohnVint: Then "visible" and "atomic" really have next to nothing to do with each other, and the use of the word "atomic" is unfortunate.

Comment: I've removed 2 my comments and will try to answer with one. To me, @cHao thought that static variable is automatically defined as volatile (as it's common to many instances of the class). My answer is no, as even static variables access is `cached` to different threads accessing it. If that was not his question, what's the other reason 3rd class is use static variable?

Comment: @archer: No, i don't care about `volatile` or not.  That's not relevant to atomicity; in any case, an `int` will have one value, never part of one and part of another.  That's what atomicity is, and it seems to be getting a bit confused with visibility.

Comment: @cHao You're right in the case I gave they aren't related.  As far as the atomicity of memory though, volatile under x86 is implemented via CAS which is an atomic memory swap.

Comment: @cHao I have amended the first sentence to remove the confusion. I have assumed that the `static` in the question was a typo. Maybe it wasn't...

Comment: @JohnVint: 32-bit writes on x86 are already atomic.  All CAS does is *swap* two values atomically.  Which has nothing to do with `volatile`.

Comment: @cHao for an int it makes no difference, for a long or a double, it does (non volatile long or double assignement is not guaranteed to be atomic - volatile long or double assignment is guaranteed to be atomic).

Comment: the whole idea of getters / setters is to provide a way to alter behavior depending on the situation (do some additional checks for example). With volatile approach you lose the benefit of getters / setters as you getter / setter is limited to one atomic operation

Comment: @Funtik in the OP's example, volatile is all that was required. If the class become more complex, volatile might or might not be enough. For example volatile would still be good enough if your setter becomes `if (value != 0) aField = value;`.

Comment: @Funtik:  Fact is, without additional synchronization over and above what a getter/setter alone can possibly provide, you're limited to one atomic operation either way.  `obj.setX(obj.getX()+1);` involves getting the property *and releasing the lock* before reacquiring it for the setter, and it's quite possible for another thread to jump in there in between locks and screw around.  Whereas `obj.addToX(1);` could easily acquire a lock that covers the whole operation.  Decent atomicity requires encapsulation.  Real encapsulation, not this farting around with get/set methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `DontKnowIfThreadSafeButMostLikelyYes` is not thread safe because a `static` variable is not different from an instance variable from point of synchronization. Besides this the result will not be the same as in the other cases.

Also the second question is opinion based.

Comment: Though you are correct in your conclusion you don't lead the OP into the direction of *why* it's not thread-safe.  If the field was non-static it would still be thread-unsafe

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know *DontKnowIfThreadSafeButMostLikelyYes* is not thread-safe, because **2 threads** could set and get **aField** at the same moment -> problem

There is no difference if you put the static or not. Both would be not thread-safe.

I think there is no real preferred idom. In this case I would choose the first way. But you can also use the second one or you could use locks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is DontKnowIfThreadSafeButMostLikelyYes thread-safe?
```

No, because when getter & setter are being called the same moment getter might return old value.

```
What would be the preferred idiom and why?
```

In this case the 2nd class is correctly synchronized & is thread safe